# dcolumn not available. Solution or alternative (for use with texreg)?

Tags: r, texreg

I would like to use `dcolumn` to align table columns in a `texreg` output, as recommended in the user guide for `texreg`.

However, `dcolumn` seems not available for the current version of R:

```
> install.packages("dcolumn")
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘dcolumn’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)
```

Any solution/recommendation for an alternative approach?
(Tables will be compiled with knitr in RStudio.)

Comment: I might rephrase the question above. `dcolumn` is no longer updated and can no longer be used to align table columns when using `texreg`. How should table columns in `texreg` be aligned?

Answer (score 1):

dcolumn is not an R package (CRAN) but it is a LaTex package (CTAN). Have you tried calling the dcolumn package in your markdown file?

here example with beamer:

[How can I use latex packages in R markdown beamer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514610/how-can-i-use-latex-packages-in-r-markdown-beamer)