# How to align table columns i PDF with `texreg`

Tags: r, pdf, texreg

The `texreg` package is supposed to write tables with nicely aligned columns, using the command `dcolumn = TRUE`, see the user's guide for the [`texreg` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/texreg.pdf), dated 3 March 2018. The command calls the `dcolumn` package, but `dcolumn` is not available for the current version of R (see earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375041/dcolumn-not-available-solution-or-alternative-for-use-with-texreg)).

Without alignment, tables generated by `texreg` do not look good in a PDF document compiled with `knitr`. (The `knitr` package uses the Times New Roman font family for PDF, not monospaced font.) One (not optimal) solution might be to change the font in the whole PDF to monospace. I have found no reference to changing the font family in the `knitr` documentation, but a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421235/changing-font-in-pdf-produced-by-rmarkdown) at SO discusses it. I had no success using the suggested solution. It would anyway not be a great solution to use monospace font throughout a document that combines text and code.

So, how should users of `texreg` make sure tables in a document knitted to PDF have aligned columns in a table?

This question is very similar to an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375041/dcolumn-not-available-solution-or-alternative-for-use-with-texreg), but no suggestion was provided to the earlier question. It is probably important for most users of `texreg` to have a solution for aligning table columns after the `dcolumn` package has become outdated.

Comment: Perhaps this might help somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that and report back here.

Comment: `dcolumn` is not at CRAN, but at CTAN and part of Latex.

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375041/dcolumn-not-available-solution-or-alternative-for-use-with-texreg

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Speaking form myself, I switched to `kable` and `kableExtra`.