# R stargazer function produced table is not aligned because of dcolumn

Tags: stargazer

When using stargazer my tables are not aligned. R studio says because of package dcolumn is not installed. The problem is that when I try to install that package I received a message saying:package ‘dcolumn’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Does someone knows how to deal with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can install `dcolumn` (which is not an R package, it's a Tex package) from here:

https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn?lang=en

This previous question can help:

[dcolumn not available. Solution or alternative (for use with texreg)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375041/dcolumn-not-available-solution-or-alternative-for-use-with-texreg)